# Dokku - /home/dokku/.sshcommand: No such file or directory

Tags: dokku

I've installed Dokku on a VPS running CentOS7. When I 'git push dokku master' I'm getting...

`git remote set-url dokku dokku@mydomain.com:trial`

`git push dokku master
cat: /home/dokku/.sshcommand: No such file or directory
fatal: ''trial'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

When I try and ssh in I also get the same error...

`ssh dokku@mydomain.com
cat: /home/dokku/.sshcommand: No such file or directory
Connection to mydomain.com closed.`

cat /var/log/secure ...

`Nov  7 10:06:29 Callisto sshd[19912]: Accepted publickey for dokku from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 50002 ssh2: RSA SHA256:Y0ueDcZEJWQd9H3FsetReYTDPwJPob6zm9p4Dpt4fOE
Nov  7 10:06:29 Callisto sshd[19912]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dokku by (uid=0)
Nov  7 10:06:29 Callisto sshd[19914]: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 50002:11: disconnected by user
Nov  7 10:06:29 Callisto sshd[19914]: Disconnected from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 50002
Nov  7 10:06:29 Callisto sshd[19912]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dokku`

Prior to pushing I'm creating the app on the server...

`dokku apps:create trial`

To add my public ssh key to server I used `dokku ssh-keys:add dokku id_rsa.pub`

Looking at another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832246/git-remote-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-dokku) it seems that I am in fact missing .sshcommand in /home/dokku/ . Any ideas on how to fix this or what could have gone wrong? This has been driving me crazy the last couple of days.

Answer (score 4):

You must have deleted it at some point. Run the following commands to set everything up again:

```
echo '/usr/bin/dokku' > /home/dokku/.sshcommand
chmod 0644 /home/dokku/.sshcommand
chown dokku:root /home/dokku/.sshcommand
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realised I never responded. Using your advice as a pointer above, I had a look through the dokku repo and noticed some of the expected files were missing after install. Seemed to be a result of Docker not having been installed properly. This appeared to be caused because I was trying to run Docker on an OpenVZ VPS. When I moved to a KVM VPS everything worked properly.

Comment: You made my day, thank! I lost this file when initial CentOS server setup of Dokku, not sure why it is not represent after initial Dokku setup on this OS.